# How can I list all amino acids in a protein using PyMOL?

Tags: pdb, pymol

What is the command in PyMOL for listing all the amino acids in a specific protein, say, 1a62.pdb?

Answer (score 2):

At the command, change the current directory to your target directory:

```
cd my-directory-path-containing-my-files
```

Load the file:

```
load 1a62.pdb
```

Then you can either print to screen or save to a file:

```
print(cmd.get_fastastr('all'))

save 1a62.fasta
```

Comment: A small caveat for `get_fastastr` is that the fasta sequence returned does not include gaps in the numbering, therefore, a multiline command using `[int(atom.resi) for atom in cmd.get_model('name CA').atom]` may be required in some cases.